# Retrieve Blackberry OS in Blackberrywebworks using javascript

Tags: blackberry-webworks

How to retrieve Blackberry OS version in Blackberrywebworks using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `blackberry.system.softwareVersion` and don't forget to add `<feature id="blackberry.system" />` to your config.xml

You can find full docs here
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.system.html#.softwareVersion